# Rails 4 loads JS as plain text when trying to use AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

I'm trying to create a simple page with two columns. On the left column, the user can fill in a form. On the form submit, I would like the right column to refresh (via AJAX) and populate a div with a @url string that's been created in the controller. Right now, the form submission does not fire the code on my .js page at all--instead it redirects away from the page and loads my .js as plain text in the browser. This should be so simple--what am I doing wrong?

In config/routes:

```
    root 'home#home'
    post '/pixify', to: 'home#pixify', as: "pixify",  format: 'js'
```

In HomeController:

```
    class HomeController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :html, :js
      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

      def home
      end

      def pixify
        @url = "http://example-url.com"
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js { render :layout => false }
        end
      end
    end
```

In views/home/home.html.haml:

```
   %div#container
     %div.left-column
       = form_tag pixify_path, :remote => true do
         %fieldset
            %ul
                %li
                    %label{:for => "url-id"} URL ID:  
                    %input{:type => "text", :name => "url-id"}

            %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Generate url", :class => "button"}

     %div.right-column
       %div#generated-url
```

In views/home/pixify.js.erb:

```
    console.log("This is working");   // but it isn't
    $('#generated-url').html('http://www.justanexample.com');
```

Comment: Check the output HTML of your form, it should have `data-remote="true"`, also, you need to include the `jquery-ujs` script that came with rails.

Comment: The HTML output does have `data-remote="true"` and both `require jquery' and `require jquery_ujs` are required in application.js. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @seesarahcode - Can you try by removing `format: 'js'` options from route and `render :layout => false` from the controller ?

Comment: @VenkatCh  If I remove those two lines (or just the `format: 'js'` line), I get an `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error for the respond block in the home#pixify action. If I remove the `render :layout => false` line, I don't get any errors, but it still renders my .js file as plain text. Is there some other combination that might work?

Comment: @seesarahcode - Please do one more debug.. i.e comment `respond_to :html, :js` from controller and try ? (yn) If it doesn't work please try to provide your console output of request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571085/missing-rails-js-with-jquery-rails) set me on the right path. The jquery_ujs wasn't working right because of the javascript tag in application.html.erb. Turns out that I needed to change this:

`<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`

to this:

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

I had changed that line while troubleshooting a separate template issue and forgotten to switch it back. I also removed the render statement from the controller (per @VenkatCh's answer--thank you!), and now everything is working great.

`respond_to do |format|
    format.js
 end`

Answer (score 2):

js.erb files render as text if you don't have the jquery_ujs lib included in your application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

I bet that's what the difference was between the 'default' and the 'application' files.

And you'll need the following gems in your gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Comment: just adding the `//= require jquery_ujs` in application.js fixed this for me in rails 5. Didn't sem to need the `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'`